# What are some alternatives to Shapley values which drop additivity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory

Shapley values seem to be the standard answer to "how should a coalition split the rewards of their cooperation", but I'm curious about alternatives.

The [standard characterization of Shapley values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley_value#Characterization) says that Shapley values are the unique coalition payments which satisfy a bunch of properties. Three of them (efficiency, symmetry, and null player) seem pretty necessary for any "reasonable" or "practical" coalition payment rule, but the last one (linearity) does not.

If I didn't care for linearity (or its close synonyms, additivity and aggregation):

- What sorts of payment rules become available?
- What other properties of Shapley values are maintained?
- What other properties would produce a uniquely characterized payment rule?

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you may be interested in the pre-kernel/pre-nucleolus. These solutions do not satisfy neither linearity nor additivity nor aggregation.
The pre-nucleolus is a single-valued solution like the Shapley value that satisfies in addition covariance, anonymity, and the reduced game property.

For more information, have a look into the book of B. Peleg, and P. Sudhölter (2007), Introduction to Theory of Cooperative Games. Springer Publisher.

[Book Info here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-72945-7)